# How to display db values into datetime picker dynamically?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datetimepicker

I want to display my db date time values dynamically into the calender and time input field dynamically, but it already working statically.

This my script code :

```
<script>
    var disabledDateTime = {'2017-12-14':[['2:30am','3:00am'],['6:30am','9:00am']],'2017-12-17':[['1:00am','3:00am'],['5:30am','2:00pm']]};
    $(function() {
        $('#pickTime').timepicker();
        $('#pickDate').datepicker({
            'format': 'yyyy-m-d',
            'autoclose': true
        }).on('changeDate',function(e){
            var ts = new Date(e.date);
            var m = ts.getMonth()+1;
            var dt = ts.getFullYear() + '-' + m + '-' + ts.getDate();
            var opt = {'disableTimeRanges': []}
            if(typeof(disabledDateTime[dt])!='undefined'){
                $('#pickTime').timepicker('setTime', '');
                opt = {'disableTimeRanges': disabledDateTime[dt]}
            }
            $('#pickTime').timepicker('option',opt);
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this my html code:

```
<input id="pickDate" type="text" class="date" />
<input id="pickTime" type="text" class="time" />
```

In this line

```
var disabledDateTime = {'2017-7-14':[['2:30am','3:00am'],['6:30am','9:00am']],'2017-7-17':[['1:00am','3:00am'],['5:30am','2:00pm']]};
```

I added statically dates, but I want to display dynamically using php and this my php code:

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("select * from dtpicker");

    $calc = [];
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result))
    {
        $calc[] = [
            $row->date => [
                $row->starttime,
                $row->endtime
            ]
        ];
    }
?>
<script>
    var disabledDateTime = <?= json_encode($calc) ?>;
</script>
```

But I'm unable to display dynamically, how to do this?